# PeerJS Connection made, but no data transfer

Tags: javascript, webrtc, peerjs

I've been trying to get two browsers communicate with each other using PeerJS, however am unable to overcome this hurdle.

As far as I can tell, the chrome console indicates that a successful connection has been established between the two browsers, however I cannot get either client to receive any data.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script src="http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="peer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <label id="yourID">Your ID is: </label><br>
    <label id="currentConn">You are currently connected to: </label>
    <div>
        <button id="connectButton">Connect to this ID</button>
        <input type="text" id="toConnectID">
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div>
        <textarea id="playArea"></textarea><br>
        <button id="sendMessage">Send Message</button>
    </div>
        <script>
            console.log("JS Started");
            var peer1 = new Peer({key: 'lwjd5qra8257b9', debug: 3});

            document.getElementById("connectButton").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sendMessage").disabled = true;

            peer1.on('open', function(id){
                console.log("Peer1 ready");
                document.getElementById("connectButton").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("yourID").innerHTML = "Your ID is: "+id;

                peer1.on('data', function(data){
                    console.log("Data received: "+data);
                    document.getElementById("playArea").value = data;
                });
            });

            peer1.on('connection', function(dataConnection){
                document.getElementById("sendMessage").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("currentConn").innerHTML = "You are currently connected to: "+dataConnection.peer;
                conn = dataConnection;
            });


            $("#connectButton").click(function(){
                ID = document.getElementById("toConnectID").value;
                conn = peer1.connect(ID);
                document.getElementById("currentConn").innerHTML = "You are currently connected to: "+ID;
                document.getElementById("sendMessage").disabled = false;
            });




            $("#sendMessage").click(function(){
                text = document.getElementById("playArea").value;
                conn.send(text);
                console.log("Data sent: "+text);
            });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The end goal is to have the browsers communicate over a local network, so code is purely to test the PeerJS library.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your on('data') subscriber should be under conn.on('data') instead of peer1.on('data') . 
and you need conn.on('data') in 2 places to be able to receive data in both end. One for the client who establish connection itself, under conn.on('data'), one for the client who got connected, under peer1.on('connection'). If you remove any1 of them, you will see only one end is receiving data.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script src="http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="peer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <label id="yourID">Your ID is: </label><br>
    <label id="currentConn">You are currently connected to: </label>
    <div>
        <button id="connectButton">Connect to this ID</button>
        <input type="text" id="toConnectID">
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div>
        <textarea id="playArea"></textarea><br>
        <button id="sendMessage">Send Message</button>
    </div>
        <script>
            console.log("JS Started");
            var peer1 = new Peer({key: 'lwjd5qra8257b9', debug: 3});

            document.getElementById("connectButton").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("sendMessage").disabled = true;
            var conn;
            peer1.on('open', function(id){
                console.log("Peer1 ready");
                document.getElementById("connectButton").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("yourID").innerHTML = "Your ID is: "+id;


            });

            peer1.on('connection', function(dataConnection){
                document.getElementById("sendMessage").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("currentConn").innerHTML = "You are currently connected to: "+dataConnection.peer;
                conn = dataConnection;
                conn.on('data', function(data){
                    console.log("Data received: "+data);
                    document.getElementById("playArea").value = data;
                });
                console.log("Connected")

            });


            $("#connectButton").click(function(){
                ID = document.getElementById("toConnectID").value;
                conn = peer1.connect(ID);
                conn.on('open',function(){
                    console.log("open")
                    conn.on('data', function(data){
                        console.log("Data received: "+data);
                        document.getElementById("playArea").value = data;
                    });
                })
                document.getElementById("currentConn").innerHTML = "You are currently connected to: "+ID;
                document.getElementById("sendMessage").disabled = false;
            });




            $("#sendMessage").click(function(){
                text = document.getElementById("playArea").value;
                conn.send(text);
                console.log("Data sent: "+text);
            });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Holy cow this actually worked! Many thanks - your help is much appreciated.